# How can I add category more than one

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make kind of a movie website and I added some categories. But you know movies/series don't have one category. I need to add more than one. I tried to do `category: "Mind-Bending","Ominous",` it didn't work.

```
const posters = [
{
    title: "Dark",
    category: "Mind-Bending",
    img: "https://i.hizliresim.com/kl5ikc6.png",
    desc: `A family saga with a supernatural twist, set in a German town where the disappearance of two young,
    children exposes the relationships among four families.`
}]

const btnContainerDOM = document.querySelector(".categorie-cont")
const moviesContainerDOM = document.querySelector(".movies")
const btnList = ["All","Mind-Bending","Chilling","Ominous"]

btnList.forEach((value) => {
  let button = document.createElement("button")
  button.innerHTML = value
  button.setAttribute("data-id",value)
  button.addEventListener("click",buttonClick)
  btnContainerDOM.append(button)
})

function buttonClick(){
  const result = (this.getAttribute("data-id") === "All") ? posters : posters.filter((item) 
=> {
    return item.category == this.getAttribute("data-id")
});
addMovie(result) 
}
```

---

Edit: I've tried this, but this didn't work either

```
function buttonClick() {
var i, j;
const result = (this.getAttribute("data-id") === "All") ? posters : posters.filter((item) => {
    for (i = 0; i < posters.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < posters[i].category.length; j++) {
            return item.category[j] == this.getAttribute("data-id")
        }
    }
});
addMovie(result)
```

Comment: If you want your category to hold more than one category, then you can just define `category` as an array which can hold 0 to many categories.

Comment: You should share your HTML as well. That can help to understand what you're struggling

Comment: I didn't understand how to do that

Comment: Should use category as array and use logic to check if your object item sub category list in main category list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to have more categories, you can define `category` in `posters` as an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of several categories like so:

```
const posters = [
{
    title: "Dark",
    category: ["Mind-Bending", "Chilling"],
    img: "https://i.hizliresim.com/kl5ikc6.png",
    desc: `A family saga with a supernatural twist, set in a German town where the disappearance of two young,
    children exposes the relationships among four families.`
}]
```

Naturally, this means you would need to adapt your code a bit.

For your method `buttonClick`, you can use `.includes()` to check if your array or string contains a substring. In your case, you want to check if the array of `category` contains the selected category.

```
function buttonClick(){
  const dataId = this.getAttribute("data-id");

  const result = dataId === "All" ? posters : posters.filter((item) => {
    return item.category.includes(dataId);
  });

  addMovie(result) 
}
```